# LocalStorage Struggles

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Am trying to print the values inside the textboxes on the page.

Upon clicking the button, the values appear on the page but only for a split second.

What can I do to make the values remain on the page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Local Storage - JavaScript <h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
        <input id="inpKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter key...">
        <input id="inpValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value...">
        <button type="button" id="btnInsert">Insert Data</button>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Local Storage</legend>
        <div id="lsOutPut"></div>
    </fieldset>


<script src="action.js">

const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
const lsOutPut = document.getElementById("lsOutPut");

btnInsert.onclick = function(){
    const key = inpKey.value;
    const value = inpValue.value;

    if(key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        location.reload();
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        const keyx = localStorage.key(i); 
        const value = localStorage.getItem(keyx); 

        lsOutPut.innerHTML += `${keyx}: ${value}</br> `
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `location.reload()`, that's why its reloading the page, not sure why you have there, but its the cause:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Local Storage - JavaScript <h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
        <input id="inpKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter key...">
        <input id="inpValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value...">
        <input type="button" id="btnInsert" value="Insert Data"/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Local Storage</legend>
        <div id="lsOutPut"></div>
    </fieldset>


<script>

const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
const lsOutPut = document.getElementById("lsOutPut");

btnInsert.onclick = function(){
    const key = inpKey.value;
    const value = inpValue.value;

    if(key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        const keyx = localStorage.key(i); 
        const value = localStorage.getItem(keyx); 

        lsOutPut.innerHTML += `${keyx}: ${value}</br> `
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have `location.reload()`, I presume to clear the div with previous values. This is reloading the page and causing the split second issue. Switch it for the following to clear the box before printing the new values.

```
if(key && value) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      lsOutPut.innerHTML = '';
}
```

While unrelated, it's also worth noting you aren't closing your `<h2>` tag.

```
<h2>Local Storage - JavaScript</h2>
```

Comment: I used your code and I can now se any output on the page. Thank you very much amcquaid!